# Why is there no Tuple1 Literal for single element tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, tuples

Python has `(1,)` for a single element tuple.  In Scala, `(1,2)` works for `Tuple2(1,2)` but we must use `Tuple1(1)` to get a single element tuple.  This may seem like a small issue but designing APIs that expect a Product is a pain to deal for users that are passing single elements since they have to write Tuple1(1).

Maybe this is a small issue, but a major selling point of Scala is more typing with less typing.  But in this case it seems it's more typing with more typing.

Please tell me:
1) I've missed this and it exists in another form, or
2) It will be added to a future version of the language (and they'll accept patches).

Comment: I don't understand what's the purpose of Tuple1.

Comment: @paradigmatic It allows a value to implement the `Product` interface (e.g. so that you can pass it in to a method that takes a `Product` as an argument). Of course, you lose static typing this way.

Comment: @paradigmatic Sometimes third-party tools implement things that require tuples of any arity as input. For example, when using breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix to create numeric matrices, one of the constructors takes a variadic argument list of tuples, where each tuple corresponds to a row. If you want to create an Nx1 matrix (single column, but typed as a Matrix and not as a Vector), then you might want to pass in a variadic list of single-element tuples to that constructor. The point is that even if one can't anticipate why someone might need this, it's too shortsighted to omit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def value2tuple[T](x: T): Tuple1[T] = Tuple1(x)
```

The implicit conversion will only apply if the argument's static type does not already conform to the method parameter's type. Assuming your method takes a `Product` argument

```
def m(v: Product) = // ...
```

the conversion *will apply* to a non-product value but will *not* apply to a `Tuple2`, for example.  Warning: all case classes extend the `Product` trait, so the conversion *will not apply to them either*.  Instead, the product elements will be the constructor parameters of the case class.

`Product` is the least upper bound of the `TupleX` classes, but you can use a type class if you want to apply the implicit Tuple1 conversion to all non-tuples:

```
// given a Tupleable[T], you can call apply to convert T to a Product
sealed abstract class Tupleable[T] extends (T => Product)
sealed class ValueTupler[T] extends Tupleable[T] { 
   def apply(x: T) = Tuple1(x) 
}
sealed class TupleTupler[T <: Product] extends Tupleable[T] { 
   def apply(x: T) = x 
}

// implicit conversions
trait LowPriorityTuple {
   // this provides a Tupleable[T] for any type T, but is the 
   // lowest priority conversion
   implicit def anyIsTupleable[T]: Tupleable[T] = new ValueTupler
}
object Tupleable extends LowPriorityTuple {
   implicit def tuple2isTuple[T1, T2]: Tupleable[Tuple2[T1,T2]] = new TupleTupler
   implicit def tuple3isTuple[T1, T2, T3]: Tupleable[Tuple3[T1,T2,T3]] = new TupleTupler
   // ... etc ...
}
```

You can use this type class in your API as follows:

```
def m[T: Tupleable](v: T) = { 
   val p = implicitly[Tupleable[T]](v) 
   // ... do something with p
}
```

If you have your method return the product, you can see how the conversions are being applied:

```
scala> def m[T: Tupleable](v: T) = implicitly[Tupleable[T]](v)
m: [T](v: T)(implicit evidence$1: Tupleable[T])Product

scala> m("asdf") // as Tuple1
res12: Product = (asdf,)

scala> m(Person("a", "n")) // also as Tuple1, *not* as (String, String)
res13: Product = (Person(a,n),)

scala> m((1,2)) // as Tuple2
res14: Product = (1,2)
```

Comment: This approach seems complete, but I wonder why not just use an implicit parameter, for instance have toTuple take (implicit m: TupleConverter[T]) which has implicit values doing similar to what you did.  That seems like it would be fewer lines of code.  Comments on this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting, but it sounds like you mean that your API method would still take a `Product` argument. If so, case classes would _not_ be wrapped in a Tuple1 since they already extend the `Product` trait (and therefore have no need of conversion).

Comment: @Oscar Boykin [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514380/define-a-function-with-tuples/6515307#6515307) might offer a simpler approach. Maybe this is what you had in mind with your comment?

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. That example is almost perfectly relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You could, of course, add an implicit conversion to your API:

```
implicit def value2tuple[A](x: A) = Tuple1(x)
```

I do find it odd that `Tuple1.toString` includes the trailing comma:

```
scala> Tuple1(1)
res0: (Int,) = (1,)
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me by seconds. :)

Comment: What if you're making a DSL that wants to accept either single items, or tuples of items.  If I do value2tuple, a tuple2 -> Tuple1[Tuple2[A,B]], which is not what I want.  I want non tuple -> Tuple1[A], and TupleX -> TupleX.  Can I do this with some kind of constraints on the type in value2tuple?

Answer (score 2):

Python is not statically typed, so tuples there act more like fixed-size collections. That is not true of Scala, where each element of a tuple has a distinct type. Tuples, in Scala, doesn't have the same uses as in Python.

Comment: The static typing seems irrelevant to me.  When you print a Tuple1 in scala it is printed as (1,).  It seems inconsistent that you can not use that as a literal.

Comment: @Oscar The mkString of Scala types are not valid literals. For instance, `List("abc")` is printed as `List(abc)`. Instead, they target readability. In this case, the extra comma is there just to indicate it represents a tuple. By the way, the trailing comma _was_ valid up to a few versions back, and was removed because it added too much complexity for too little gain.

Comment: @Oscar And the static typing point is that `Tuple1` is not used in Scala. In Python, it has use as a fixed width collection of size 1, but tuples in Scala are _not_ collections, so there's no use for it.

Comment: Tuples are Product instances, which are a bit like collections, so I'm not sure I agree with this argument.

Comment: @Oscar All product provides is an iterator. An iterator is not a collection, and no one uses tuples for its `Product`.