# Converting single argument into an HList with shapeless Generic

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the following method:

```
def lift[P <: Product, L <: HList](params: P)(implicit hl: Generic.Aux[P, L]) = {
  directive[L](_(hl to params))
}
```

and it perfectly works if i pass more then two arguments:

```
val result  = lift("string", 'a', 10) // compiles
val result2 = list(true, 5) // compiles
```

But when i'm passing a single argument it can't resolve implicit:

```
val failes = lift("string")
```

It can't find Generic implicit for `[String, Nothing]`, why does it work in other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the result of auto-tupling, which is a Scala (mis-)feature that causes `lift(true, 5)` to be parsed as `lift((true, 5))` when there's no `lift` method with the appropriate number of values (two, in this case). The compiler won't automatically wrap a single value in a `Tuple1`, however—you just get a compiler error.

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998559/334519) for more details about auto-tupling, and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/zwG8o2YzCWs) for some reasons auto-tupling is a terrible thing to include in your language.

There are a couple of possible workarounds. The first would be to create an implicit conversion from values to `Tuple1`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478548/334519). I wouldn't personally recommend this approach—every implicit conversion you introduce into your code is another mine in the minefield.

Instead I'd suggest avoiding autotupling altogether. Write out `list((true, 5))` explicitly—you get a lot of extra clarity at the cost of only a couple of extra characters. Unfortunately there's no comparable literal support for `Tuple1`, so you have to write out `lift(Tuple1("string"))`, but even that's not too bad, and if you really wanted you could define a new `liftOne` method that would do it for you.